# Water pressure passing through lock gates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics

Imagine that there are two locks on a canal, both side by side, of equal size and filled with water. Would both empty at the same rate and pressure when the lock gates were simultaneously opened if one contained a large vessel and the other did not?

Comment: -1 Not clear : Do the locks contain the same volume of water when the gates are opened? Or are the water levels equal when this happens?

Comment: @sammygerbil `filled with water` A lock is defined to be "full" when the water level is the same as the canal upstream. So the same level.

Comment: @Rodney But the question says *of equal size and filled with water*. That implies they start with the same volume of water. The question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

A boat displaces it's own weight of water when floating.

This means that a full lock containing a boat should be at the same *level* as a full lock that doesn't contain a boat. If the locks are both *filled* simultaneously they will reach the full level when both locks and the upstream section of the canal (called a pound) are in equilibrium.

Drive the boat into one of the locks, and the level doesn't change.

The same principle applies driving a boat out of an empty lock.

Since water pressure is proportional to depth, then yes, in theory, the result should be identical. The starting and ending levels will be exactly the same, and the same amount of water will be emptied from each lock.

However, *no two locks are ever identical*. Real locks have leaks, blockages and all sorts of imperfections on both the upstream and downstream gates. Furthermore, each time you operate a lock you change the level of the canal, so you might have to factor that into your experiment...

An interesting feature is that not only does the *level* of the water remain unchanged as the vesseles arrive / depart, the total *mass* and therefore *weight* is also unchanged. This feature is neatly exploited by the [Anderton Boat Lift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderton_Boat_Lift) and others.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, water is not compressible. Assuming the amount of water in each lock is the same, then the water level in the lock with a ship would be higher. The volume of the water above the 'no ship' level is equal to the volume of the ship submerged in the water, and this 'raised' water has the same weight as the ship:

Volume of water raised by ship: $V_{displaced-water}$ = Submerged volume of ship

Weight of this water raised by ship equals the ship's weight: $\rho_{water}\times V_{displaced-water}\times g = W_{ship}$

Since the level of water is higher in the lock with the ship, if the water outlet channels/piping is the same, then the lock with the ship will empty faster.

Comment: This answer assumes the boat was dropped into the lock after it was filled with water. In reality boats are driven into the lock, and displace their own weight in water back out of the gate. The lock with the boat will have less water and be at the same level

Comment: @Rodney granted, if that is the assumption. I have stated my assumption and its consequences. It may be of use to people trying to understand buoyancy.

Comment: Even if both locks *start* with the same volume of water, they will still *finish* at the same "empty" level, so in that scenario the one containing the boat actually has to ditch more water. I think the problem with the question is the definitions of `full` and `empty` which is actually terminology for two different levels.

Comment: @Rodney, true, it would start with the same amount of water but would have to dump more to equalise levels with a lock at a lower height. I assumed 'empty' to mean 'empty'. Your answer is more realistic, and I have merely given an exploration of the buoyancy principle. It deserves a thumbs up.